# c trying to pass the time and date to another function

Tags: c, time

I'm trying to pass the time and date that I called from my main function to another function on my C program.

I've tried saving the current time & date in a char to try and pass that over however I get invalid declaration which I believe is because I'm trying to save something into the array after deceleration.

```
int main ()
{
  time_t f;
  struct tm * b;
  time(&f);
  b = localtime(&f);
  //char myTime [] = b;
  printf("Local time is %s \n", asctime(b));
}

void function2()
{
 //going to recieve time here for later use
}
```

I need the time for when the program ran so I can save it into a file.

error was:

error: invalid initializer

Shouldn't their be another way around it? I don't have to use char, it was something I thought off. Not sure if there's better alternatives

Comment: Can you please give the compiler error message, with line number?

Comment: Just pass `f` or `b` like you would pass any other variable? You *do* know how to create functions taking arguments?

Comment: britishTime is not declared

Comment: @JoachimPileborg what would f and b, be stored as?

Comment: They are already stored in the `main` function as `f` and `b`. Later when you call `function2` you pass one (or both) to that function.

Comment: `void function2(struct tm *b)`, I'd assume? Then you call it in main with `function2(b);`

Comment: I'm assuming function2(struct tm first, time_t second)

Comment: With added `#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>` it compiles fine here.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, when I tried to compile it in VS 2012 I get this compiler error Error 1 error C4996: 'localtime': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using localtime_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Comment: @Bobski short answer: compile, click on the error message and press F1. This will show up a [web page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C4996);k(VS.ErrorList)&rd=true) that contains further explanations.

Comment: @Bobski, you might want to switch your time functions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just pass the time value to that function, and make the function save it in a file as you need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "time.h"

int time2file(time_t t) {
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    fprintf(f, "Some text: %ul\n", t);
    fclose(f);
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    time2file(time(NULL));
    return 0;
}
```

If you need to save the time value in another format, you could do something like:

```
int time2file(time_t t){
    struct tm *b = localtime(&t);
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    fprintf(f, "Local time is %s", asctime(b));
    fclose(f);
    return 1;
}
```

Of course, you should verify whether you actually opened the file, and other errors, but that's out of the scope of your question I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "time.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    time_t f;
    struct tm b;
    time(&f);
    localtime_s(&b, &f);
    //char myTime [] = b;
    char buffer[256];
    asctime_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), &b);
    printf("Local time is %s \n", buffer);
}
```